# libtinfo.so.6: no version information available

Tags: shell, environment-variables, conda, zsh, ld

After installing cuda and cudnn with miniconda, whenever I start a new shell with the current user. I am always getting warnings about `/usr/bin/zsh: /some/path/to/miniconda3/lib/libtinfo.so.6: no version information available`.

It seemed that `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set to `/some/path/to/miniconda3/lib`, but after extensive digging (examined all possible rc files in `etc`, `$HOME`, I am still unable to locate where exactly this variable is set. Also `echo`ing `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on the top of every RC file yields this path (both login shell and non-login shell).

I would like to find out a way to disable this warning (presumably by unsetting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, is there any suggestions?

EDIT: After restarting my desktop, the error went away.. Is there any explanation why this happened? Is there some other config being executed prior to starting up the shell (in some cache file) which will be cleared after reboot?